# use Postman response variable from a previous call to make a POST call

Tags: json, postman

In postman, I want to make a call to (example) https://api/test/test

once I get that response I want to add that response to a body of another call (POST) (example) https://api2/test2/test2 and then that data is sent to my application via a token.

The token is permanently set so never needs to change and is set in the header so all I need really is the above

Call 1 GET
Call 2 gets Call 1 response data and puts it in Call 2 body and then the post is made

I also want to add some text data in call 2 response body so I presume I want it to look like this

[
    {
    "event":
    {
       {{variable}}
    }
    }
]

I think i can do this through the collection runner but unsure how to put it all together o some help would be appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Refer the [LINK](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/intro-to-scripts/)

Step by Step [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHASdmCR1bE)